# Copying files into another directory using git branch

Tags: git

I'm working on building a custom application that will allow my team to work on our web application while using git and logging information. We have a development, staging and production server. In order for us to make changes to the application, it has to be done directly on the development server (licensing). We're introducing git to this now as we've had to previous version control before this. I was hoping that a developer can branch the main branch, make edits to it and view the edits in a browser, and then eventually merge the branch back in the main branch, and then push it to staging/production. Is this possible? Can I copy the branch into another directory or something similar?

Comment: How much do you know about Git? Do you come from a centralized background? You write: *Can I copy the branch into another directory or something similar?* but you don't need to use another directory; all you need is check out the branch of interest.

Comment: I highly recommend you read the basic Git [tutorial](http://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial) and [documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics). The question you ask shows a bit of a misunderstanding about the basic way in which Git works; That is, branches are not copies of the repository state, they are pointers into a specific snapshot along entire repository history.

Comment: @Jubobs I think my confusion lies in how would I point the browser to the right branch of interest, or if that's even possible. Giving them all a custom path. That's why I ask if it's possible to copy the branch into another directory.

Comment: Sure, but our point is that you wouldn't copy a *branch*, you'd clone the *entire repository* (since, I assume, you are running the actual production server off of the 'main' repository). Your intention is totally possible, you're just not quite thinking about it the right way. Have a read through the two documents I linked, you'll get a much better feel for what you want to do. But yes, once set up, you'll be able to do it and it will be a lot less painful than it would be with SVN or similar centralized repos.

Comment: @aruisdante okay, that makes sense. So everyone would be working on a clone, not a branch.

Comment: Well, they might have their own branches as well so that they're not committing directly to test/master. [This](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/index.html) is a basic guide to your typical Git workflow. Usually the repository clones would be on each developer's machines, with the 'main' clone on the production server representing the 'primary' state of the repository that everyone synchronizes with. In your case, since you have interesting license requirements, it might make sense for each dev to have a remote mountpoint onto the server where their clone lives, but same idea.